# How can I use a recursion scheme to express this probability distribution in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, probability, category-theory, recursion-schemes

This question is part theory / part implementation. Background assumption: I'm using the [monad-bayes](https://github.com/adscib/monad-bayes) library to represent probability distributions as monads. A distribution p(a|b) can be represented as a function `MonadDist m => b -> m a`.

Suppose I have a conditional probability distribution `s :: MonadDist m => [Char] -> m Char`. I want to get a new probability distribution `sUnrolled :: [Char] -> m [Char]`, defined mathematically (I think) as:

```
sUnrolled(chars|st) = 
              | len(chars)==1 -> s st
              | otherwise -> s(chars[-1]|st++chars[:-1]) * sUnrolled(chars[:-1]|st)
```

Intuitively it's the distribution you get by taking `st :: [Char]`, sampling a new char `c` from `s st`, feeding `st++[c]` back into `s`, and so on. I believe `iterateM s` is more or less what I want. To make it a distribution we could actually look at, let's say that if we hit a certain character, we stop. Then `iterateMaybeM` works.

Theory Question: For various reasons, it would be really useful if I could express this distribution in more general terms, for instance in a way that generalized to the stochastic construction of a tree given a stochastic coalgebra. It looks like I have some sort of anamorphism here (I realize that the mathematical definition looks like a catamorphism, but in code I want to build up strings, not deconstruct them into probabilities) but I can't quite work out the details, not least because of the presence of the probability monad.

Practical Question: it would also be useful to implement this in Haskell in a way that used the recursion schemes library, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not smart enough to thread monads through the recursion schemes, so I relied on recursion-schemes-ext, which has the anaM function for running anamorphisms with monadic actions attached.

I did a (really ugly) proof of concept here:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Data.Functor.Foldable (ListF(..), Base, Corecursive)
import Data.Functor.Foldable.Exotic (anaM)
import System.Random

s :: String -> IO (Maybe Char)
s st = do
  continue <- getStdRandom $ randomR (0, 2000 :: Int)
  if continue /= 0
    then do
    getStdRandom (randomR (0, length st - 1)) >>= return . Just . (st !!)
    else return Nothing


result :: (Corecursive t, Traversable (Base t), Monad m) => (String -> m (Base t String)) -> String -> m t
result f = anaM f

example :: String -> IO (Base String String)
example st = maybe Nil (\c -> Cons c $ c:st) <$> s st

final :: IO String
final = result example "asdf"

main = final >>= print
```

A couple of notes

1. I mocked out your `s` function, since I'm not familiar with `monad-bayes`
2. Since our final list is inside a monad, we have to construct it strictly.  This forces us to make a finite list (I allowed my `s` function to randomly stop at around 2000 characters).

EDIT:

Below is a modified version that confirms that other recursive structures (in this case, a binary tree) can be spawned by the result function.  Note the type of `final` and the value of `example` are the only two bits of the previous code that have changed.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies #-}
import Data.Functor.Foldable (ListF(..), Base, Corecursive(..))
import Data.Functor.Foldable.Exotic (anaM)
import Data.Monoid
import System.Random

data Tree a = Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf
  deriving (Show, Eq)
data TreeF a b = BranchF a b b | LeafF

type instance Base (Tree a) = TreeF a
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f (Branch a left right) = Branch (f a) (f <$> left) (f <$> right)
  fmap f Leaf = Leaf
instance Functor (TreeF a) where
  fmap f (BranchF a left right) = BranchF a (f left) (f right)
  fmap f LeafF = LeafF
instance Corecursive (Tree a) where
  embed LeafF = Leaf
  embed (BranchF a left right) = Branch a left right
instance Foldable (TreeF a) where
  foldMap f LeafF = mempty
  foldMap f (BranchF a left right) = (f left) <> (f right)
instance Traversable (TreeF a) where
  traverse f LeafF = pure LeafF
  traverse f (BranchF a left right) = BranchF a <$> f left <*> f right

s :: String -> IO (Maybe Char)
s st = do
  continue <- getStdRandom $ randomR (0, 1 :: Int)
  if continue /= 0
    then getStdRandom (randomR (0, length st - 1)) >>= return . Just . (st !!)
    else return Nothing


result :: (Corecursive t, Traversable (Base t), Monad m) => (String -> m (Base t String)) -> String -> m t
result f = anaM f

example :: String -> IO (Base (Tree Char) String)
example st = maybe LeafF (\c -> BranchF c (c:st) (c:st)) <$> s st

final :: IO (Tree Char)
final = result example "asdf"

main = final >>= print
```